# How Java List and Map Object Internal Structure is preserved inside Aerospike?

Tags: java, key-value-store, aerospike

1. Suppose we create one Java LinkedHashMap `dllMap`. Now its implemented using doubly linked list.
2. Suppose we write this `dllMap` to Aerospike as

   ```
   value = Value.get(dllMap) 
   aerospike.write(..., value);
   ```

   Now, in this case:

   1. When we write LinkedHashMap to Aerospike do we loose dll structure of LinkedHashMap?
   2. When we read back map from Aerospike, do we need to rebuild dll again?

Note: I don't want to write Map as Object(BLOB) inside Aerospike as I want to write some LUA procedures that operate on map.

Answer (score 2):

After reading [the doc](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/data-types.html) and source of aerospike-java-client again, I have to correct.

1. Not really. The LinkedHashMap will convert to map.
2. Not really. When you got back, you actually get an object with type HashMap.

Comment: So its limitation of Aerospike to loose internal implementation/Data structure used to store data ? and we need to explicitly convert HashMap to LinkedHashMap